# variable not in scope - list comprehesion

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm trying construct a function that return a list with the sum of tuples elements when is higher than 100.

```
resultSum :: [(Integer)] -> [Integer]
resultSum (x:xs) = [ sumT | let sumT = fst x + snd x in sumT + trd x, sumT > 100 ]

trd (_,_,x) = x
```

I'm receiving the message:

> Not in scope: `sumT'

I figured that when I use the `let` I'm specifying who is my variable

PS: I need to user `let`and list comprehesion

Comment: What do you want to do? All 3-tuples in a list of 3-tuples with a sum greater than 100?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to get all 3-tuples in a list of 3-tuples where the sum of the components is greater than 100 and you want somehow to use let inside the listcomprehension.

First of all: the type of your expression is not correct, it should probably be:

```
resultSum :: [(Integer,Integer,Integer)] -> [Integer]
```

Try the following solution:

```
resultsum xs3 = [x+y+z | (x,y,z) <- xs3, let sumT=x+y+z in sumT>100]
```

BTW: The `let in` right of the `|` is local to the right part of `|`, you cannot use it left of `|`. However, you can use `let` as a standalone clause on the right side of `|` (thank chi) and then you can use it on the left side of `|` like

```
resultsum xs3 = [sumT | (x,y,z) <- xs3, let sumT=x+y+z, sumT>100]
```

Comment: In general, in list comprehensions it is common to use `let x=e, ...` instead of `let x=e in ...` since the former makes `x` available for all the rest of the comprehension, while the latter only lasts until the comma. In this specific case it does not matter, of course, since the comprehension ends right there.

Comment: @chi It does matter because if we don't use `in`, we can use `sumT` on the left side of the `|` as well. So your comment is the actual answer to OP's question.